# pandas: get only common rows w.r.t a column between two dataframes and sum up the values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

my_array1 = np.array([
["A",5],
["A",10],
["B",5],
["E",55],
["E",55],
])

my_array2 = np.array([
["A",22],
["B",55],
["C",22],
["D",55],
])


df1 = pd.DataFrame(my_array1, columns = ['symbol','score'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_array2, columns = ['symbol','score'])
```

What i want is form the above two dataframes is

first sum all the values in each table w.r.t score

```
my_array1 = np.array([
["A",5],
["A",10],
["B",5],
["E",55],
["E",55],
])

becomes

my_array1 = np.array([
["A",15],
["B",5],
["E",110],
])

and

my_array2 = np.array([
["A",22],
["B",55],
["C",22],
["D",55],
])

becomes


my_array2 = np.array([
["A",22],
["B",55],
["C",22],
["D",55],
])
```

and then

get the only the common between both w.r.t column symbol and again show the total

i.e

```
From

my_array1 = np.array([
["A",15],
["B",5],
["E",110],
])


and 

my_array2 = np.array([
["A",22],
["B",55],
["C",22],
["D",55],
])

get


my_array2 = np.array([
["A",37],
["B",60],
])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need convert to numeric first, then `groupby` with `sum`

```
df1.score = pd.to_numeric(df1.score)
df2.score = pd.to_numeric(df2.score)
com = np.intersect1d(df1.symbol,df2.symbol)
pd.concat([df1,df2]).loc[lambda x : x['symbol'].isin(com)].groupby('symbol').sum()
Out[44]: 
        score
symbol       
A          37
B          60
```

The numpy array only accept one type for each sub-array , so the whole array become ovbject not numeric anymore.

Check the output

```
my_array1
Out[35]: 
array([['A', '5'],
       ['A', '10'],
       ['B', '5'],
       ['E', '55'],
       ['E', '55']], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: `concat([df1.groupby('symbol').sum(),df2.set_index('symbol')]` what does this do. why are not doing sum for df2

Comment: this is great answer also

Comment: `.loc[lambda x : x['symbol'].isin(com)]`  what does it do

Comment: @Santhosh filter the row which df1 and df2 share the same item ~

Comment: it somethings same as `pd1 = pd.concat([df1,df2]); pd1.loc[pd1['symbol'].isin(com)]`

Comment: also now how to sort w.r.t score descending order

Comment: @Santhosh you can do it with sort_values()

Comment: `np.intersect1d()` how to use it if i have more than two dataframes

Comment: @Santhosh try reduce 
`from functools import reduce 
 reduce(np.intersect1d, [df1.A, df2.A, df3.A])`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
# converting to numeric
df1['score'] = df1['score'].astype(int)
df2['score'] = df2['score'].astype(int)

out1 = df1.groupby('symbol').sum()
out2 = df2.groupby('symbol').sum()

out = out1.add(out2).dropna()
```

Comment: this is more easy to understand

Comment: @Santhosh `symbol` is index by default after `groupby`.